# random position of divs in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, positioning

I'm trying to make Divs to appear randomly anywhere on a webpage with javascript. So a div appears then disappears, then another div appears somewhere else on the page then disappears, then another div appears again in another random spot on the page then disappears, and so on. 
I'm not sure on how to generate random units in pixels or what technique to use to generate random positions.

How do I do that? Here's my code:

```
var currentDivPosition = myDiv.offset(),
    myDivWidth = myDiv.width(),
    myDivHeight = myDiv.height(),
            var myDiv = $('<div>'),
    finalDivPositionTop, finalDivPositionLeft;

myDiv.attr({ id: 'myDivId', class: 'myDivClass' }); // already defined with position: absolute is CSS file.

// Set new position     
finalDivPositionTop = currentDivPosition.top + Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 );
finalDivPositionLeft = currentDivPosition.left + Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 );

myDiv.css({ // Set div position
  top: finalDivPositionTop,
  left: finalDivPositionLeft
});

$('body').append(myDiv);

myDiv.text('My position is: ' + finalDivPositionTop + ', ' + finalDivPositionLeft); 

myDiv.fadeIn(500);

setTimeout(function(){

  myDiv.fadeOut(500);

  myDiv.remove();       

}, 3000);
```

Comment: How are you defining `myDiv`?

Comment: @Lance: like this, var myDiv = $('div');

Comment: The area you are positioning it should be X: 0 to max(x) - divwidth, any other way will position it outside viewable area every now and then, or show a bias towards right side of the screen.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. I'm randomly varying the size of the div within a fixed range, then setting the position so the object is always placed within the current window boundaries.

```
(function makeDiv(){
    // vary size for fun
    var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
    var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
    $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
        'width':divsize+'px',
        'height':divsize+'px',
        'background-color': color
    });

    // make position sensitive to size and document's width
    var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

    $newdiv.css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':posx+'px',
        'top':posy+'px',
        'display':'none'
    }).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(100).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, function(){
      $(this).remove();
      makeDiv(); 
    }); 
})();
```

Edit: For fun, added a random color.

Edit: Added `.remove()` so we don't pollute the page with old divs.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/QcUPk/8/

Comment: Thanks very this what I wanted. But why is it that, when I remove `$newdiv = $('<div/>').css...`, the code doesn't work anymore?

Comment: `$newdiv` is a variable pointing to the newly created, unattached div. If you remove that, there's no new div to position and add to the DOM. If you want to consolidate things, you can put both `.css()` methods into one block (below the position calculations).

Comment: Thanks Ken, I know why it didn't work, it's because there was no content inside the div, i.e. text, ...etc. so it wouldn't show up. but it works now

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have this HTML:

```
<div id="test">test div</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
#test {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:70px;
    background-color:#d2fcd9;
}
```

Using jQuery, if you use this script, whenever you click the div, it will position itself randomly in the document:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    var docHeight = $(document).height(),
        docWidth = $(document).width(),
        $div = $('#test'),
        divWidth = $div.width(),
        divHeight = $div.height(),
        heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
        widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

    $div.css({
        left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
        top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax )
    });
});
```

The way this works is...first you calculate the `document` width and height, then you calculate the `div` width and height, and then you subtract the `div` width from the `document` width and the `div` height from the `document` height and consider that the pixel range you're willing to put the `div` in (so it doesn't overflow out of the document). If you have padding and border on the `div`, you'll need to account for those values too. Once you've figured out the range, you can easily multiple that by `Math.random()` and find the random position of your `div`.

So once more: first find the dimensions of the container, then find the dimensions of your element, then subtract element dimensions from container dimensions, and THEN use `Math.random()` on that value.

The basic idea is encapsulated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5mvKE/

Comment: Hi how can I change the text inside div and also make the div automatically randomized instead of click

Answer (score 0):

Some bugs:

1. You missed to position the div absolutely. Otherwise it will not
   work.
2. I think you need to ad 'px' to the numbers.
3. The map is made of strings

Right in your jQuery css setup:

```
myDiv.css({
    'position' : 'absolute',
    'top' : finalDivPositionTop + 'px',
    'left' : finalDivPositionLeft + 'px'
});
```

Comment: the map can also be of the words without strings.

Answer (score 0):

I changed an existant code by this one for our website, you can see it on [tweefox.nc](http://www.tweefox.nc)

```
<script>
            function draw() {
                $(canvas).attr('width', WIDTH).attr('height',HEIGHT);
                con.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
                for(var i = 0; i < pxs.length; i++) {
                    pxs[i].fade();
                    pxs[i].move();
                    pxs[i].draw();
                }
            }

            function Circle() {
                this.s = {ttl:8000, xmax:10, ymax:4, rmax:10, rt:1, xdef:950, ydef:425, xdrift:4, ydrift: 4, random:true, blink:true};

                this.reset = function() {
                    this.x = (this.s.random ? WIDTH*Math.random() : this.s.xdef);
                    this.y = (this.s.random ? HEIGHT*Math.random() : this.s.ydef);
                    this.r = ((this.s.rmax-1)*Math.random()) + 1;
                    this.dx = (Math.random()*this.s.xmax) * (Math.random() < .5 ? -1 : 1);
                    this.dy = (Math.random()*this.s.ymax) * (Math.random() < .5 ? -1 : 1);
                    this.hl = (this.s.ttl/rint)*(this.r/this.s.rmax);
                    this.rt = Math.random()*this.hl;
                    this.s.rt = Math.random()+1;
                    this.stop = Math.random()*.2+.4;
                    this.s.xdrift *= Math.random() * (Math.random() < .5 ? -1 : 1);
                    this.s.ydrift *= Math.random() * (Math.random() < .5 ? -1 : 1);
                }

                this.fade = function() {
                    this.rt += this.s.rt;
                }

                this.draw = function() {
                    if(this.s.blink && (this.rt <= 0 || this.rt >= this.hl)) {
                        this.s.rt = this.s.rt*-1;
                        this.dx = (Math.random()*this.s.xmax) * (Math.random() < .5 ? -1 : 1);
                        this.dy = (Math.random()*this.s.ymax) * (Math.random() < .5 ? -1 : 1);
                    } else if(this.rt >= this.hl) this.reset();
                    var newo = 1-(this.rt/this.hl);
                    con.beginPath();
                    con.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                    con.closePath();
                    var cr = this.r*newo;
                    g = con.createRadialGradient(this.x,this.y,0,this.x,this.y,(cr <= 0 ? 1 : cr));
                    g.addColorStop(0.0, 'rgba(255,255,255,'+newo+')');
                    g.addColorStop(this.stop, 'rgba(255,255,255,'+(newo*.2)+')');
                    g.addColorStop(1.0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0)');
                    con.fillStyle = g;
                    con.fill();
                }

                this.move = function() {
                    this.x += (this.rt/this.hl)*this.dx;
                    this.y += (this.rt/this.hl)*this.dy;
                    if(this.x > WIDTH || this.x < 0) this.dx *= -1;
                    if(this.y > HEIGHT || this.y < 0) this.dy *= -1;
                }

                this.getX = function() { return this.x; }
                this.getY = function() { return this.y; }
            }
            $(document).ready(function(){
//              if( /Android|AppleWebKit|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
//              } else {
                    if(document.getElementById('pixie')) {
                        WIDTH = $(window).width();
                        HEIGHT = $(window).height();    
                        canvas = document.getElementById('pixie');
                        $(canvas).attr('width', WIDTH).attr('height',HEIGHT);
                        con = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        pxs = new Array();
                        rint = 60;
                        for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                        pxs[i] = new Circle();
                        pxs[i].reset();
                        }
                        setInterval(draw,rint);
                    }
//              }
            });
        </script>
```