# Randomly Position A Div

Tags: java, php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm looking for a way to randomly position a div anywhere on a page (ONCE per load).

I'm currently programming a PHP-based fantasy pet simulation game. One of the uncommon items on the game is a "Four Leaf Clover." Currently, users gain "Four Leaf Clovers" through random distribution - but I would like to change that (it's not interactive enough!).

**What I Am Trying To Do:**

The idea is to make users search for these "Four Leaf Clovers" by randomly placing this image anywhere on the page: [image: this image] (my rendition of a four leaf clover)

I'd like to do this using a Java/Ajax script that generates a div, and then places it anywhere on the page. And does not move it once it's been placed, until the page is reloaded.

I've tried so many Google searches, and the closest thing that I've found so far is [this (click)](http://jsfiddle.net/redler/QcUPk/8/), from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796743/random-position-of-divs-in-javascript). But, removing the .fadein, .delay, and .fadeout stopped the script from working entirely. I'm not by any means a pro with Ajax. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: you don't need ajax for this, only jquery/javascript. And of course it's possible. I suggest that you post the code YOU created in a jsFiddle, so it would be easier to help you out.

Comment: Generate two random numbers, set these for the top and left edges of your absolutely positioned div.

Comment: @Th0rndike - That's a relief! Java is so much easier for me to understand! Any ideas on how to code something like this? =)

Comment: @ScottS - I could do that easily with PHP, but how would I ensure that I am using valid numbers for all screen resolutions?

Comment: See Robert's answer below - he uses percentages, instead of pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This still works. simply use makeDiv() to create new one.

```
function makeDiv(){

var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
$newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
    'width':divsize+'px',
    'height':divsize+'px',
    'background-color': color
});

var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

$newdiv.css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'left':posx+'px',
    'top':posy+'px',
    'display':'none'
}).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(100);
};

makeDiv();
```

Comment: I do have one last question though (and it might be a dumb one), ...where would I add in the <img> tag with link (so that it's not just a random box - but an interactive clover image)?

Comment: Simply add: 

    $newdiv.html('<img src="somepath"/>')

to the function

Answer (score 6):

In javascript you can generate a a random number between 0 and 1 using `var randomNumber = Math.random();`

If you give your div absolute positioning, you can then do

```
div.style.top = (100*Math.random()) + "%";
div.style.left = (100*Math.random()) + "%";
```

this will set it in a random location. By setting the left and top css properties to a random percentage between 0 and 100.

Answer (score 0):

It the first link suits you, do not remove fadein it shows up the element. Or remove 'display':'none' and then you can remove all you wrote.