# adding a div to a random location inside the window

Tags: jquery, html, viewport

Okay so I have this code where every 2 seconds double the amount of divs that are in the body are appended to the body. however I want this divs to be at a random location inside of the viewport how might i achive that? only the first div in my code actually appears in a random location each time the rest just stack up and leave the viewport here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hy4fq/2/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Project: An exploding game</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body, html {
width: 960;
height: 500%;
}
div.box {
position: relative;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: orange;
}
div.exploding {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("body").append("<div class='box'></div>");
    // add new div *2
    $("div.box").each(function() {
             var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*501);
            $(this).css({'margin-left': numRand});
                setInterval(function()                {$(".box").clone().appendTo("body");}, 3000);

})  

    });





</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the link that led me to this answer: [random position of divs in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796743/random-position-of-divs-in-javascript)

Firstly, you need to update the random value each time the function is called. In your example it was inside an each function, and if you look in developer tools you'll see that it only sets that value the first time.

Secondly, if you want the divs to be placed inside the viewport, using position:absolute on the appearing divs is better than position:relative (in this case) because if you use position relative the height of the body could increase every time a div is added.

```
function makeDiv() {
        var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
        var divsize = 100;
        var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
        var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();
        $newdiv = $("<div class='exploding'></div>").css({
            'left': posx + 'px',
                'top': posy + 'px'
        });
        $newdiv.appendTo('body').delay(2000).fadeIn(100, function () {
            //$(this).remove();
            makeDiv();
        });
    }
```

Here's a demo of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/hy4fq/3/

Comment: Thnak you now the only issue is that it is only adding one div at a time not double the amount of divs on the page however im sure I can get it to work with your code I appriciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep redefining numbRand, it's only being defined once and then used for every div.  Maybe create another function and return just numbRand, then call it each time so it pulls a random number each time.