# adding divs but making them stay inside the viewport

Tags: jquery, html, css

okay so I'm trying to append a certain number of divs to the body without changing the width or height of the body. In other words the new divs have to stay inside the viewport here is my code:

```
divAmount = 6;
$(document).ready(function(){
windowWidth = $(window).width();
windowHeight = $(window).height();


game();


$('body').css({
    "max-width" : windowWidth,
    "max-height" : windowHeight 
    });

});

function game(){ 


for (var i = 0; i < divAmount; i++) {
        $("<div class='box' />").appendTo("body").css({
            "margin-left" : Math.floor(Math.random() * windowWidth - 100) + 1,
            "margin-top" : Math.floor(Math.random() * windowHeight - 100) + 1
        });
}

$('.box').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('box').addClass("exploding");
}); 




};
```

this is making it so the divs are added correctly; however, they aren't staying inside the viewport

Comment: Your question is vague, but [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) may do what you want.

Comment: @Liam how is it vague im appending new divs and i want them to stay inside the viewport

Comment: @Liam, he don't need masonry, all he wants is to make the divs stay inside the limit of the width and height and should not produce any scrolls or a messup in the UI!

Comment: I have no idea what you want, that's why it's vague. Your adding div's to the body and using a random number to set the margin. why? What is this meant to achieve? why are you setting the body width? The body should be 100% of your page, that's what a body does, etc. etc.

Comment: @Liam I'm sorry. Okay so what I'm doing is creating a game for my own training skills. the game adds a div .box every round the point is to click on them before time runs out. right now I'm in the beggining stages of my game where I'm just trying to add the divs and making them stay inside the viewport

Comment: so you want the div's to appear at a random position within the body?

Comment: @liam correct and each round the divs get doubled

Comment: someone else has done the same here [random position of divs in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796743/random-position-of-divs-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a working fiddle I made - http://jsfiddle.net/Kn3V3/

If you give the .box divs absolute positioning, they *kinda* don't take up any space.

```
.box {
    background: red;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

However, as someone said above, you should make a container div the height and width of the window instead of the body, and then the body 100% h/w. (That's what I've done in the fiddle)

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
min-width: 120px;
max-width: 240px;
```

This way, you will control the min and max values for the width. Similarly you can control the height of the body tag too.

This way, all the new divs that will be added will go in the body just as a stream. Instead of messing up the height and width.

You can use `screen.width` and `screen.height` for the values of `min-width` `min-height` as well as for `max-width` `max-height`.

**Staying inside the viewport?**

You can also try to add `overflow` property to the body tag to remove scroll bar, but I don't think that's what you want!

Then simply use `min` and `max`.

Comment: I tried using just the max-width because I don't really care about the min-width do I need to use both for them to work properly?

Comment: No, you just need to set the property for what you need. They don't need to be used along, you can simply just use `max-width` without having to use `min`. :) Good luck..