# Make text appear somewhere else on hover

Tags: html, css

I have an image, and when I hover over the image, I want to make text appear somewhere else on the screen.  I've found lots of solutions making text appear on the image, but not somewhere else on the page.  Any ideas?

Here's what I'm trying:
HTML:

```
<div class="dan-profile-picture"></div>
blah blah blah
<div class="dan-profile">lots of text</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.dan-profile-picture {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
    -moz-border-radius: 75px;
    background: url(./images/dan.jpg) no-repeat;
    border:3px solid black;
}
div.dan-profile {
    display:none;
}
div.dan-profile-picture:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
}
div.dan-profile-picture:hover + div.dan-profile {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: look at this to get started : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796743/random-position-of-divs-in-javascript

Comment: Want like this ah? http://jsfiddle.net/p6umwb22/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you prefer jQuery :

```
 $('.dan-profile-picture').hover(function () {

        var posx = Math.floor(Math.random() * $("body").width());
        var posy = Math.floor(Math.random() * $("body").height());
        $('.dan-profile').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
                'left': posx + 'px',
                'top': posy + 'px',
                'display': 'block'
        });
    });
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3cngvh2/)

**update**

to hide the div, you can use either a call back function in existing jQuery - *as mentioned in comments by user3008011*

```
$('.dan-profile-picture').hover(function () {

        var posx = Math.floor(Math.random() * $("body").width());
        var posy = Math.floor(Math.random() * $("body").height());
        $('.dan-profile').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
                'left': posx + 'px',
                'top': posy + 'px',
                'display': 'block'
        });
    },function(){                  //this is call back function
        console.log('out');        //will be triggered when main 
        $('.dan-profile').hide();  //function completes
    });
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3cngvh2/3/)

second way - *since you are new to jQuery* - you can trigger `hide` even on `mouseout`

```
 $('.dan-profile-picture').mouseout(function () {
        $('.dan-profile').css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    });
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3cngvh2/2/)

Comment: Thanks NoobEditor, I like this.  One question, how do I make the text disappear, when my mouse leaves hover? (I'm new to jQuery)

Comment: @Jason : you mean, you have to *hide* text when cursor is moved out of `.dan-profile-picture`?

Comment: @Jason hover out events can just be written after the hover function. Like so. http://jsfiddle.net/d3cngvh2/1/

Comment: Yeah - I've been mucking around, I think I need to add a ', function() after.

Answer (score 0):

make dan-profile a child of dan-profile-picture

```
.dan-profile-picture{
position:relative;

}

.dan-profile{
position:absolute;
right: -30px /* whichever value you desire */
top: -30px /*whichever value you desire */
display:none;
}

.dan-profile-picture:hover .dan-profile{
display:block;
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
div.dan-profile-picture {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
    -moz-border-radius: 75px;
    background: url(./images/dan.jpg) no-repeat;
    border:3px solid black;
}
.dan-profile-picture:hover {
    opacity:0.5;
}

.dan-profile{display:none;}
.dan-profile-picture:hover + .dan-profile{display:block;}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6t1xj52/1/)**

Remember that with the `+` selector, the element must be the directly next element. If there are elements in between, this selector won't work and you'll have to resort to javascript.

[See this page for more info on css selectors](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Number 7. of that list is the one I used for your user case

*"This is referred to as an adjacent selector. It will select only the element that is immediately preceded by the former element."*

Comment: Thanks for this.  Seems to work.  One quick followup, if I replace 'blah blah blah' with <br>, it stops working.  Why is that?

Comment: @Jason : this answer and your question title conflict, you asked to make it appear somewhere else and now this answer just hides on hover!!!....Mind explaining?? :\