# HTML make multiple on hovers make text appear at specific place on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a table where each different row & column holds a different image resembling a piece of data. My aim is to be able to hover over each different image and text unique to each image appears but I want each different piece of text to appear in the same place, for example an empty row at the bottom of the table and each hover text will appear in that row

How can I go about creating this? I have read [Make text appear somewhere else on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864893/make-text-appear-somewhere-else-on-hover) but not sure if that can be converted

Comment: have you tried? Where did you get stuck at? To me this looks a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make text appear somewhere else on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864893/make-text-appear-somewhere-else-on-hover)

Comment: This doesn't look like a new problem to me? Just position all hover items absolute to the bottom of the relative table. All the rest is the same as example given?

Comment: Sorry. How do I go about positioning the hover items absolute to the bottom of the table?