# Array value in randomly positioned div

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Using this - [random position of divs in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796743/random-position-of-divs-in-javascript) as a starting point I am trying to randomly position divs containing text from an array.

Current code (predominately copied Ken Redler's answer in the linked post):

```
(function makeDiv(){
    var divsize = 200;
    var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);

    //set up the array to hold the random div content
    var boastsText = [];
    var i = 0;
    $(".boast ul li").each(function() { boastsText.push($(this).text()) });

    $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
        'width':divsize+'px',
        'height':divsize+'px',
        'color': color
    });

    // make position sensitive to size and document's width
    var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

    $newdiv.css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':posx+'px',
        'top':posy+'px',
        'display':'none'
    }).html(boastsText[i]).appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn(100).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, function(){
      $(this).remove();
      makeDiv(); 
    }); 
})();
```

The only thing I have really added is the setting up of the array `var boastsText = []` and the `each` function that populates that array.

The problem I have is I need to iterate over the array so each new div created uses the next item as it's content i.e. div 1 uses array item 0, div 2 uses item 1 etc... until it reaches the end of the array and then starts the process again.

Comment: Do you have a working example of this? How are you calling `makeDiv()`?

Comment: can you put `var boastsText = []` outside of `makeDiv()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your script a little bit to use a recursive function in order to iterate over the array and maintain the delay and fadeIn/Out you have:

```
(function() {
    //set up the array to hold the random div content
    var boastsText = [];
    $(".boast ul li").each(function () {
        boastsText.push($(this).text());
    });


    function makeDiv(i){
        var divsize = 200;
        var color = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);

        var $newdiv = $('<div/>').css({
            'width':divsize+'px',
            'height':divsize+'px',
            'color': color
        });
        // make position sensitive to size and document's width
        var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
        var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();

        $newdiv.css({
            'position':'absolute',
            'left':posx+'px',
            'top':posy+'px',
            'display':'none'
        }).html(boastsText[i]).appendTo('body').fadeIn(100).fadeOut(500, function() {
          $(this).remove();
          if (i === boastsText.length) return;
          makeDiv(++i); 
        }); 
    }

    //Start the recursion
    makeDiv(0);

}());
```