# Circle Multiplier Issue

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

What I am trying to accomplish is everytime I click on the circle in my project it multiplies in random areas in the browser ultimately filling the browser up with circles. I am struggling with coming up with the correct function to do so in vanilla javscript ECMA 5. Here is what I have so far any guidance would be appreciated. The thought process here is to create a clone and then append the clone in a random place using math.random. When I run this code nothing appears to happen.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CircleMaker</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="ball"></div>

</body>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var circle = document.getElementById('ball'); 

circle.addEventListener('keydown', circleMultiplier);

function circleMultiplier(e){
    var cln = circle.cloneNode(true);

    math.random(circle.appendChild(cln));
}
```

main.css

```
html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

#ball{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

[image: first image]
UPDATE 1

I am working on the function portion of it I found something that is close to it on here [random position of divs in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4796743/7039895) and am trying to translate it to what I want it to do. So far here is my function:

```
var circle = document.getElementById('ball'); 

circle.addEventListener('keydown', circleMultiplier);

function circleMultiplier(e){
    var posx = (Math.random() * ($(document).width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($(document).height() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

    newDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    newDiv.style.top = posx+'px';
    newDiv.style.height = posy+'px';
    newDiv.style.display = 'none';



}
```

Update 2

This is what my code looks like so far, however, I am getting the following error message

> Uncaught TypeError: bod.append is not a function

```
var bod = document.getElementsByTagName("body")
var circle = document.getElementById('ball'); 

circle.addEventListener('click', circleMultiplier);

function circleMultiplier(){
    var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
    var posx = (Math.random() * document.width - divsize).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * document.height - divsize).toFixed();

    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');


    newDiv.classList.add('ball');
    newDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    newDiv.style.top = posx+'px';
    newDiv.style.left = posy+'px';

    bod.append(newDiv);



}
```

UPDATE 3

The code below does what I need it to do however it's not creating at random places on the screen it is just creating on top of the div in place see image:

```
var circle = document.getElementById('ball'); 

circle.addEventListener('click', circleMultiplier);

function circleMultiplier(){
    var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
    var posx = (Math.random() * (document.width - divsize).toFixed());
    var posy = (Math.random() * (document.height - divsize).toFixed());

    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');


    newDiv.classList.add('ball');
    newDiv.style.top = posx+'px';
    newDiv.style.left = posy+'px';
    newDiv.style.position = 'absolute';

  console.log(newDiv);

    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);



}
```

UPDATE 4

I got the new divs to appear however there are still no circles appearing in random places this is the code I have:

```
var circle = document.getElementById('ball'); 

circle.addEventListener('click', circleMultiplier);

function circleMultiplier(){
    var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
    var posx = (Math.random() * (document.body.clientWidth - divsize).toFixed());
    var posy = (Math.random() * (document.body.clientWidth - divsize).toFixed());
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');


    newDiv.classList.add('ball');
    newDiv.style.cssText = 'top:'+posx+'px; left:'+posy+'px; position:absolute;';


    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);



}
```

Here is the way it looks see console:

[image]

Comment: There is no `math.random`. And [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) wouldn’t take any argument. There’s also no positioning happening. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: There are a number of misunderstandings in the way you use functions and references here. Your `math.random(circle.appendChild(cln));` is probably the worst offender... what do you expect this line to do exactly ? give random values to x and y of the element ? more ? Because it's doing none of that

Comment: I am not getting any errors, however, I get what you are saying in regards to the x and y axis. Should I be moving towards offsetx and offsety? And figuring out how to randomly generate their numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working hard at this I finally figured it out the following is the correct function that gave me the results I needed:

```
var circle = document.getElementById('ball'); 

circle.addEventListener('click', circleMultiplier);

function circleMultiplier(){
    var divsize = ((Math.random()*100) + 50).toFixed();
    var posx = (Math.random() * (document.body.clientWidth - divsize).toFixed());
    var posy = (Math.random() * (document.body.clientWidth - divsize).toFixed());
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');



    newDiv.style.cssText = 'top:'+posx+'px; left:'+posy+'px; position:absolute; width: 200px; height: 200px;background-color: red; border-radius: 100px;';


    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);



}
```

Here is what it looks like when I click:

[image: Final]

Answer (score 0):

What you basically need is the following:

1. A container to hold the elements (which has the height and width of the page)
2. A starting element on which you can click to create more nodes.
3. A logic to place the elements at random locations on the page.

Below is a working example. You need to finish the rest by adding logic as per point #3.

https://js-qbwqev.stackblitz.io/

Comment: Can you look at my update above and let me know if I am on the right track?