# How to create a rain effect that is triggered by an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to make an image fall, similar to a rain effect, but I only want it triggered by an event listener.

Currently, I'm appending a div and animating the falling effect, but each additional event trigger is then appended below/next to the first.

```js
function appendImage() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute('src', 'http://pixelartmaker.com/art/3ba7f5717ac3c63.png');
  $('#action').append(img);
}
```

```css
@keyframes slidedown {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 150%;
  }
}

img {
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-name: slidedown;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Test Button" onclick="appendImage();" />
<div id="action"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I'm trying to get the image to spawn from a random place on the x axis but always from the top of the screen.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYbapw) here.

Comment: I'm not sure if it fully answers your question, but there is some good info about making a div appear at random locations within window limits here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796743/random-position-of-divs-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used *fixed position* here so that the elements can be independently moved across the viewport - now you can use *top* value for your animation and *left* to randomly spread it horizontally.

Also note the usage of `animation-fill-mode: forwards` which ensures that after animation the image do not come back to the top of the window.

See demo below and [**`updated codepen here`**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XwWbQg):

```js
var rainDiv = document.querySelector('#action');
function appendImage() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute('src', 'http://pixelartmaker.com/art/3ba7f5717ac3c63.png');
  img.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 'vw';
  rainDiv.appendChild(img);
}
```

```css
img {
  position: fixed;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-name: slidedown;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 0;
}

@keyframes slidedown {
  to {
    top: 120%;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Test Button" onclick="appendImage();" />
<div id="action"></div>
```