# How to generate random position for dots in square?

Tags: javascript

I have to make a gray Square which has inside multiple dots with a specific category. When i click Category 1 button, there will be show only dots with cat1 class. If user will click All, all dots will be visible. Square should be rensponsive and can be swipe on mobiles (like maps or something). Dots are alredy made as empty spans.

```css
.plan__category-btns {
  display:flex;
  list-style: none;
}
.plan__category-btns li {
  margin: 10px;
  
}

.plan__dot {
  display:block; 
  width:5px; 
  height:5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.plan__dot.cat1 {
  background: red;
}
.plan__dot.cat2 {
  background: green;
}
.plan__dot.cat3 {
  background: yellow;
}
.plan__dot.cat4 {
  background: blue;
}

.square {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<section id='plan'>
  <ul class='plan__category-btns'>
      <li>
          <button class='plan__all'>All</button>
      </li>
      <li>
          <button class='plan__one'>Category 1</button>
      </li>
      <li>
          <button class='plan__two'>Category 2</button>
      </li>
      <li>
          <button class='plan__three'>Category 3</button>
      </li>
      <li>
          <button class='plan__four'>Category 4</button>
      </li>
  </ul>

</section>

<div class="square">
      <span class='plan__dot cat1'></span>
      <span class='plan__dot cat1'></span>
      <span class='plan__dot cat1'></span>
      <span class='plan__dot cat2'></span>
      <span class='plan__dot cat2'></span>
      <span class='plan__dot cat2'></span>
      <span class='plan__dot cat2'></span>
      <span class='plan__dot cat2'></span>
      <span class='plan__dot cat3'></span>
      <span class='plan__dot cat3'></span>
      <span class='plan__dot cat3'></span>
      <span class='plan__dot cat4'></span>

</div>
```

Comment: edited. now there are dots in squere

Comment: Does this answer your question? [random position of divs in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796743/random-position-of-divs-in-javascript)

Comment: After every browser refresh, dots should be in random position in square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will show the relevant dots like this, randomly

```js
const rndBtw = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

const div = document.querySelector(".square");
const divTop = div.offsetTop;
const divRight = div.offsetWidth
const divBottom = div.offsetTop + div.offsetHeight;

// position - you may need to tweak this - it was done very quickly
[...document.querySelectorAll(".plan__dot")]
.forEach(dot => {
  dot.style.left = rndBtw(0, divRight)+"px";
  dot.style.top = rndBtw(divTop, divBottom)+"px";
});

// show clicked categories
document.getElementById("plan").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("plan")) {
    const cat = tgt.dataset.cat;
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".plan__dot")]
    .forEach(dot => dot.classList.toggle("hide", cat !== "all" && !dot.classList.contains("cat" + cat)));
  }
})
```

```css
.plan__category-btns {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.plan__category-btns li {
  margin: 10px;
}

.plan__dot {
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.plan__dot.cat1 {
  background: red;
}

.plan__dot.cat2 {
  background: green;
}

.plan__dot.cat3 {
  background: yellow;
}

.plan__dot.cat4 {
  background: blue;
}

.square {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #eaeaea;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section id='plan'>
  <ul class='plan__category-btns'>
    <li>
      <button class='plan' data-cat='all'>All</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class='plan' data-cat='1'>Category 1</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class='plan' data-cat='2'>Category 2</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class='plan' data-cat='3'>Category 3</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class='plan' data-cat='4'>Category 4</button>
    </li>
  </ul>

</section>

<div class="square">
  <span class='plan__dot cat1'></span>
  <span class='plan__dot cat1'></span>
  <span class='plan__dot cat1'></span>
  <span class='plan__dot cat2'></span>
  <span class='plan__dot cat2'></span>
  <span class='plan__dot cat2'></span>
  <span class='plan__dot cat2'></span>
  <span class='plan__dot cat2'></span>
  <span class='plan__dot cat3'></span>
  <span class='plan__dot cat3'></span>
  <span class='plan__dot cat3'></span>
  <span class='plan__dot cat4'></span>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect working with hidding and showing them but do you have any idea how to spread them out in a square random every browser refresh?

Comment: document.getElementById("plan").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("plan")) {
    const cat = tgt.dataset.cat;
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".slick__box")].forEach(dot => dot.classList.toggle("hide",cat!== "all" && !dot.classList.contains("cat"+cat)));
  }
})

I am also making a slider using slick slider and after click on category button, slides in slider should also hide. How can i get to the parent of slick__box which is slike_slide? By parent[node]?

Comment: See update for random - then ask a new question about your slider